# jquery $.ajax success response issue

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a jquery $.ajax call and in my success callback, I have this

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log('response = '+response);
    console.log('response.validate = '+response.validate);
}
```

Here's my console output in Firebug:

```
response = {"validate":true}
response.validate = undefined
```

How the heck is response.validate equal to undefined?

Comment: could you show your full ajax request...

Comment: try response['validate']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this ajax option:

```
dataType: "json"
```

If you don't tell jQuery that you are returning `JSON` and you don't set the proper headers, jQuery doesn't know how to process it.

Comment: jquery smartly detect response type.. I dont think that is the problem.

Comment: @dku.rajkumar It doesn't always do it properly.

Comment: @Kevin you must have run into this issue in the past ;)

Comment: @Catfish It used to come up pretty often on the jQuery forums.